# Update multiple row in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am trying to figure out how to update multiple row in one update() in zend framework.

I have an array of IDs named ids and I would like to update one field of all the rows of these ids.

I tried to create a where condition like that :

```
$where = Bootstrap::$db->quoteInto('id_task IN (?)', $ids);
```

And then call the update method :

```
$this->getDbTable()->update(array("deleted" => 1), $where);
```

But I have a Syntax error or access violation error and my query looks like this in the debug output :

```
array(2) {
            [0]=>
            &string(54) "UPDATE `tasks` SET `deleted` = ? WHERE (id_task IN ())"
            [1]=>
            &array(1) {
              [0]=>
              int(1)
            }
          }
```

Does anyone know how to pass an array in the where condition of an update?

Comment: Right before `$where = Bootstrap::$db...`, what does `var_dump($ids);` show?

Comment: will the `IN` operator even work in `UPDATE`? Maybe try it as a `Zend_Db_Expression` instead of `quoteInto()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
$where = Bootstrap::$db->quoteInto('id_task IN (?)', implode( ',', $ids ) );
```

Suppose your `ids` are integers and have been validated.